# remove quotes around all "true" and "false" found in object

Tags: javascript, json, regex, loops

```
  fetch("./files.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((users) => {
            var files = users.find(x => typeof x[username] !== "undefined");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(files);
            files = files.replace(/:[ ]*"false"/,':false' ).replace( /'/g,'"');

        })
```

Above I am simply trying to replace all my `"true"` and `"false"` that have quotes around them to be without the quotes *i.e.* `true` `false`.

The above errors `replace is not a function`, I have also tried `map`, and got a cannot set on `undefined error`. `users` and `files` console fine before these attempts. Any ability to do this here?

Response data looks like below after it has been `JSON.stringify`:

```
userMoves: [{id: "slz1", checked: "false"}, {id: "slz2", checked: "false"}, {id: "slz3", checked: "false"},…]
```

*Update*:  turning `files` into a string first would update the first found `false`, but not all of them.

```
files = JSON.stringify( files ).replace(/:[ ]*"false"/,':false' ).replace( /'/g,'"');
```

Comment: Could you provide the example of the response?

Comment: files isn't a string i guess, try `files = JSON.stringify( files ).replace(/:[ ]*"false"/,':false' ).replace( /'/g,'"');`

Comment: @admcfajn Hey so I just tried this, and it just updated the first found instance of false -- but did run; however it did not replace all of them

Comment: As mentioned, `files` is not a string, it's a normal JS data structure. Don't even bother with regex, just do normal iteration and directly set properties that you need set to something specific.

Comment: @AlexOwl yes I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regex or stringify.

First, we'll iterate over the array of objects in the array userMoves, then we use strict-checking to check at 1.) the value is true and 2 the value is a string, then we assign true and false respectively

```
fetch("./files.json")
.then(response => response.json())
.then((users) => {
    let files = users.find(x => typeof x[username] !== "undefined");
    for ( let file in files.userMoves ){
        if ( files[ file ].checked === "true" ) { 
            files[ file ][ 'checked' ] = true;
        }else if ( files[ file ].checked === "false" ){
            files[ file ][ 'checked' ] = false;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks looks great, but sadly is not working for me, now I am just consoling Object Object after this

Comment: What is [file] referencing? I think a more generic one could work as I need all "true" and "false" found to simply be true false

Comment: in `for ( let file in files ){`, `file` references the current index. You might want `for ( let file in files.userMoves ){`

Answer (score 1):

Your original approach should work, if you add the `g`-flag to your first regexp. The second `replace()` is superfluous. I modified the first regexp to also allow processing `"true"` values:

```js
var files=[{id: "slz1", checked: "false"},
       {id: "slz2", checked: "false"}, 
       {id: "slz3", checked: "false"},
       {id: "slz4", checked: "true"}];
var filesJSON=
  JSON.stringify(files).replace(/:[ ]*"(true|false)"/g,':$1' );
  
console.log(JSON.parse(filesJSON));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.map` to change each object to its boolean value.

```js
const data = {
  userMoves: [{
    id: "slz1",
    checked: "false"
  }, {
    id: "slz2",
    checked: "true"
  }, {
    id: "slz3",
    checked: "false"
  }]
};

function convertToBoolean(input) {
  return {
    userMoves: input.userMoves.map(item => ({ ...item,
      checked: item.checked === 'true'
    }))
  };
}

console.log(convertToBoolean(data));
```